# How to solve Bugzilla Triologygmbh CAS Plugin File does not exist at AuthCASSaml.pm line 413?

Tags: perl, plugins, cas, bugzilla

[image]I have installed Bugzilla 5.0.4 in Xampp 5.6.24-2-VC11 with ActivePerl 5.24.3.2404 and CAS plugins from https://bitbucket.org/triologygmbh/bugzilla-cas-plugin/src/master/

Changed User Authentication to CAS and CAS parameters to:

- CASserver: https://xxx.xxx.xxx/cas
- CASfullNameAttribute: id
- CASmailAttribute: mail
- CASTimeTolerance: 1000

Almost every features are working like login redirect to CAS server, redirect back to bugzilla, logout SSO. Its just when I get authenticated and redirect back to bugzilla. It gives File does not exist at loader/0x470db8/Bugzilla/Extension/CAS/Auth/AuthCASSaml.pm line 413

Anyone with experience of Bugzilla CAS or the plugin can help?

Update
For bugzilla 5.0.6
File does not exist: {"timestamp":1595816698854,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"java.lang.NullPointerException","message":"No message available","trace":"java.lang.NullPointerException\n","path":"/cas/samlValidate"} at /loader/0x8c1578/Bugzilla/Extension/CAS/Auth/AuthCASSaml.pm line 413.

Update
Same error occur with latest xampp for both bugzilla versions

Comment: *"File does not exist at .. line 413"* Looking at [line 413](https://bitbucket.org/triologygmbh/bugzilla-cas-plugin/src/0ea30329e820833df8a4db9db2c46f990b98fbbc/lib/Auth/AuthCASSaml.pm#lines-413) it seems the error comes from `XMLin()` in [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple). Can you check what `$self->callCAS()` is returning at line 414?

Comment: how should I check, like print $self->callCAS(
   $self->getServerSamlServiceValidateURL(
    $service, $ticket, $pgtUrl
   ),
   $samlBody
  )?

Comment: yes or output to stderr with `warn`. What output do you get?

Comment: not familar with perl but server internal error with print $self->getServerSamlServiceValidateURL(
    $service, $ticket, $pgtUrl
   );

Comment: print $self->callCAS(
   $self->getServerSamlServiceValidateURL(
    $service, $ticket, $pgtUrl
   ),
   $samlBody
  )
shows same line File does not exist

Comment: Do you think the error comes from `$self->callCAS()` or from `XMLin()` ?

Comment: I did see some different errors when testing out different versions of bugzilla and xampp before, cant reproduce today, sometimes it says file index.xml not found, or a array of error not found. Probably XMLin?